# Is it possible to add a checkbox to a Rich Text Field in Lighting?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to display a terms and conditions agreement using a rich text field and display that rich text field in a lightning component using

`<lightning:formattedRichText  value="{!v.rich_text_field__c}" />`

The text is displaying as desired, but I would like to have multiple check boxes inserted at every paragraph instead of just using a lighting checkbox at the bottom.
Is there any way to dynamically insert checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather think that to be more complicated approach rather than using a single checkbox outside the content itself because you would have then required to capture the checked property of the individual checkboxes those would have been rendered. And I will think that could really get complex.

Aside from this, going by [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/documentation), it doesn't seem you will be able to achieve what you are trying to using `lightning:formattedRichText`. If you refer to the **Supported HTML Tags and Attributes** section in the documentation, it doesn't seem to support any `input` type tags. You can find the complete list of supported tags out in the documentations. It also mentions:

> If you set unsupported tags via a client-side controller, those tags are removed and the text content is preserved.